# For a specific user_id get the latest rows (time-wise) that this user is in with all other users, in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am not very experienced in MySQL.

I have a table that has: unique_id (auto_increment), user_id, other_user_id, timestamp and some other fields.

Let's assume I have some values:

```
unique_id user_id other_user_id     timestamp
  1          10       11          yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
  2          11       10          yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
  3          11       12          yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
  4          11       10          yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
  5          10       12          yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

What I want to do is the following: For a single user (let's assume the user_id = 10 above) I want to find all the rows that he is in with all other users (e.g. 11, 12) and get only the last ones (time-wise) for each.

So for the data above the result should be rows 4 and 5. Row 4 because it is the last one found between 10 and 11. Row 5 because it is the last one (and only one in this example) found between 10 and 12. Same for any other rows 10 would be in with other users.

What would be the query for that?

Comment: Pro tip: we like to see prior effort here. While some people will be happy to help without any prior research from a poster, we do not want people to get into the habit of asking here in the first instance. For you next question, please show us what you have tried - it will make you a better programmer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable
JOIN (
   SELECT LEAST(user_id, other_user_id) AS user1,
          GREATEST(user_id, other_user_id) AS user2,
          MAX(unique_id) AS max_id
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY LEAST(user_id, other_user_id),
            GREATEST(user_id, other_user_id)
) AS t2 ON t1.unique_id = t2.max_id
```

The derived table is used to extract the `unique_id` value associated with the latest record per `user_id, other_user_id` pair. Since this is also, presumably, the PK of the table we can use this value in order to get the related record.

Comment: Thank you very much! This actually gives me all the unique pairs (user_id, other_user_id)  - so for the example above it returns rows 3,4,5 - so then I guess I just filter the result using the user_id I actually want to get the rows for with some additional Select....WHERE user_id = the_user_id_I_want?

Comment: In fact I just added at the end a "WHERE mytable.user_id = VALUE OR mytable.other_user_id = VALUE" and seems to give the results I want - where VALUE is the user_id I want to get the rows for -